# ypcat passwd not able to list if the user has 3 digit user id

Tags: linux, rhel, users, solaris, nis

I am trying to migrate nis server from solaris to redhat(7.5), as per the doc I have exported `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` from solaris to redhat and made NIS up and running.

If my `/etc/passwd` is e.g.:

```
james:x:554:101::/users/james:/bin/bash
kevin:x:723:103::/users/kevin:/usr/bin/bash
jerry:x:1130032140:101::/users/jerry:/usr/bin/bash
jose:x:1130032178:103::/users/jose:/usr/bin/bash
```

These are my NIS users but if I do `ypcat passwd` I am able to see only `jerry` and `jose`. `james` and `kevin` are not listed.

If I change the user id to 4 digit (e.g., `5544`) after `make` I am able to see the user.

The thing is if the user id is 3 digit `ypcat passwd` does not list that user.

Comment: There is often a configuration setting somewhere that sets the smallest (and possibly largest) UID that NIS/YP should serve.  This is so that system user accounts (such as root and others) are not included in the list.  The minimal number may well be 1000 (this is the default minimum on OpenBSD at least).

Comment: thanks, please let me know where i need to change the minimal number as 100

Comment: That's exactly why I didn't write this as an answer. I've only ever used NIS on OpenBSD and NetBSD, never on Solaris or Linux. I don't know where you would configure it on those systems, and I don't know if changing the minimum UID to 100 would be the right (or secure) thing to do.

Comment: it may be configured via something under /etc/pam.d, though I've never run NIS so don't know if there's something specific for it under that dir or if that hides somewhere else

Comment: I don't have RHEL, but look for `MINUID` and `MINGID ` lines in `/var/yp/Makefile `.

Comment: Probably relevant, even though it provides no obvious answers:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343445/user-id-less-than-1000-on-centos-7