# Changing minimum UID to SSH into server

Tags: ssh, rhel, uid

Our Linux HPC server (RHEL 7) only accepts logins to interactive sessions from users with UID >= 1000. However, some of our users have UID lower than that because their usernames were created on a separate old server using RHEL 6 (which assigns UIDs from 500).

I understand I can change the UID assigned to *new* users by changing the proper values on `/etc/login.defs`. Is there a way to change the minimum UID allowed to SSH into our server?

Also, I think the lowest UID in my case would be in the 800s, would changing the minimum allowed UID introduce any serious security issues? From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343456/68678), I understand the worst that can happen is a conflict with some program (whatever that means, exactly).

Comment: This might be a PAM configuration issue, not an sshd configuration issue.  See, for example, https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=60922&start=10

Comment: Another option would be to just update the users' UIDs

Comment: @AndyDalton, editing files on `/etc/pam.d/` looks like the key to this, unfortunately my files have a big "UNDER CFENGINE CONTROL. DO NOT EDIT! ANY CHANGES WILL BE LOST!" comment at the top, so I guess I'll have to dig deeper and learn about configuring CFEngine.

Comment: I dont know what cfengine might be, but my understanding is that the pam files are usually updated when you run `authconfig --update` when it will read changes made to `/etc/login.defs`, for example, to change `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.

Comment: @Andy, you're definitely right.  Post your comment as an answer, so Waldir can award credit?  I vote the CFEngine stuff is extraneous in our scope.